# Mod vs. Users close war

Tags: discussion, status-completed, vote-to-close, moderator-tools

A moderator closed a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494805/computer-addressing-in-a-word-organized-physical-memory) as off-topic. A few users disputed the close, believing it to be based on a misunderstanding of the question. (The moderator's comment before closing said to look up big-endian vs. little-endian, which has nothing to do with the question.) The mod reopened and reclosed the question, wiping the reopen votes. The mod also deleted his initial comment and the comments disputing the close.

Is this a valid use of mod powers? In a case like this, is the moderator supposed to have the final say on whether the question stays closed? The fact that we can vote against a mod close vote suggests that those votes are supposed to count, but the fact that the mod can override them suggests maybe not.

Comment: It's not the first time the community had a dispute with this moderator, either.

Comment: aaand it's deleted.

Comment: ... by that mod. Should I provide a screenshot?

Comment: If you feel it would add to the question, go ahead. I don't really know. Are deleted questions invisible to people who haven't already looked at them?

Comment: Don't bother.  I'll undelete the question while you guys duke it out.

Comment: Indeed, Robert Harvey has a multi-year history of precisely this kind of abusive behavior when called on his technical mistakes, though **deleting** the question is apparently a new low.

Comment: Moderators are given a binding vote, and the permission to use it.  If you want to cry modabuse, take it to Reddit.  If you want to have a constructive discussion, stay here.

Comment: @RobertHarvey this question is complaining about the reopen/close to shake off reopen votes. If the community disagrees with a mod, who should have the final say? Also note deletion / locking prevents criticisms on that question.

Comment: It got taken here, so.

Comment: Meanwhile, your pettiness in leaving it locked prevents the clear technical question from being answered.  Moderators exist to facilitate the function of the site, not to impede it.

Comment: While we are discussing your binding votes - the question you've closed as a duplicate wasn't. Either of them. Should we have posted to meta as soon as you locked it for content dispute?

Comment: There is a meta meta question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/218275/what-can-be-done-when-an-abusive-mod-closes-the-meta-thread-about-his-abuse.

Answer (score 14):

This question seems to be copy paste of an exam question without any indication of what part of it was unclear. My gut feeling is that it should be closed or we'll just get entire exams posted here. However, under the current rules I can't see any basis under which it can be closed.

Given that this question is at least controversial I would be happiest if the questions fate was decided by the community at large (certainly not overriding community votes). It seems to be heading back to closure by community votes which seems ideal.

A more constructive (and more long term useful) way to ask this question might have been to ask how to identify the next memory address when reading fixed byte words. This is more general and therefore more useful.

Comment: So much drama over a lame exam question :(

Answer (score 4):

I have been told by someone in the Teacher's Lounge that the question is answerable... Sort of.  I'll overlook the fact that this appears to be a copy/paste of a homework assignment, and reopen the question.